# How to remove anchors tags from html using php querypath

Tags: php, html-parsing, querypath

I'm working with php Querypath and I'm trying to remove anchor tags with particular href from html.

for example

```
<html>
<body>
   <div>
      <a  href="#down"></a>
      <a href="#top" ><img src="img.png" /> </a>
      <a href="#top" ><img src="img.png" /> </a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my output should be

```
<html>
<body>
   <div>
      <a  href="#down"></a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anchors with href top should be removed.

I tried with following Code

```
$html = qp($html)->find("a#top")->remove()->writeHTML();
```

But it didn't remove following anchors.

Please let me know how to achieve this in php query path.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870201/remove-anchors-from-text Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove anchor tag with `href=top`.

```
$("a[href^=#top]").remove();
```

Comment: This is how did : $anchors = $this->qp->top('a');
    foreach($anchors as $a) {
        if($a->attr('href') == '#top'){
            $a->remove(); 
        }
        
    } Thanks a lot